# How to return 0 if table empty, 1 otherwise

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgreSQL, how can i return a table containing 0 if my table is empty and a table containing 1 if my table has rows?

I need to do it in SQL, not using any other language

Comment: Do you want to return the *value* 0 or 1 if your table has rows? Or do you want to return a table containing only one row if it has rows, and nothing if it doesn't?

Comment: I want to return a table containing the value 1 if there are rows in my table and a table containing 0 if nothing is in this specific table i have.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to return a 0 or 1?  If you just want a boolean indicator, any value greater than 0 will map to true in your post-db logic.

Answer (score 22):

Use:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1) THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
       END
```

*EDIT*: Added LIMIT 1 to speed up query.

Comment: This is so wrong! This query reads a whole table to determine if it is empty. For big table it would take ages!

Comment: Could I just add a "Top 1" then to fix that?

Comment: Erm, because it's not SQLServer, Limit 1?

Comment: @Tometzky It wouldn't take ages. From [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html): *"The subquery will generally only be executed far enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion."* In other words, `LIMIT 1` is already built-in. Any implementation of EXISTS should behave the same way, because there is never any point in fetching more data.

Answer (score 13):

Might be a hack, but it works.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table LIMIT 1) AS t;
```

- The 1 selected in the sub-query could be whatever, it is just a place holder.
- The LIMIT 1 should make the sub-query very fast, regardless of table-size.

**Edit:** Rewrote a bit. Previous use of LIMIT was wrong (didn't help on large tables as I intended).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select sign(count(*)) from mytable
```

Comment: count(*) is very slow for huge tables

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
select min( c ) from (
select count(*) c
from mytab
union
select 1
from mytab
having count(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>SELECT, COUNT and LIMIT should do it.</del>

```
-- see below SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X LIMIT 1
```

**Edit:** *This doesn't work in Postgres* (8.x at least). Please see the comments and here: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/window-function-count-and-limit-td3233588.html

Happy SQL'ing.

Comment: That will just limit the number of rows returned to 1, it will still return '3' if there are 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this request in a stored procedure, with the table name as  parameter :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isEmpty(tableName text, OUT zeroIfEmpty integer) AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT 1 FROM %s LIMIT 1),0)', tableName)
INTO zeroIfEmpty;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then run this function like this :

```
SELECT * FROM isEmpty('my_table_name');
```

So you can call it with any of your table's name

Answer (score -10):

I don't think that's possible using nothing but SQL. Why can't you use any other language?

Comment: This would have been better as a comment